# Convert DateTime Format c#

Tags: c#, datetime

I would like to Convert the string in DateTime format

```
CultureInfo cultureInfoProvider = new CultureInfo("en-US");  
var lastUpdatedDate = updatedVAlue.Max();   //value is 20150219T045452:635599184921416348  
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(lastUpdatedDate,"yyyyMMddTHHmmss:fff",cultureInfoProvider);
```

I'm getting an exception 
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: What happens if the string is "20150219T045452:635"?

Comment: Your format patter says *there will be 3 digits after `:`* but your input string have a lot more than 3.

Comment: Its giving throwing an exception if i give 3 fff's or as no of digits after the semicolon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are.
This will trim your string and keep it's 3 digit tail.

```
  CultureInfo cultureInfoProvider = new CultureInfo("en-US");
  string lastUpdatedDate = updatedVAlue.Max();   //value is 20150219T045452:635599184921416348  
  string[] parse = lastUpdatedDate.Split(':');
  lastUpdatedDate = parse[0] + ":" + parse[1].Substring(0,3);
  DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(lastUpdatedDate,"yyyyMMddTHHmmss:fff",cultureInfoProvider);
```

Tested here : https://ideone.com/EIs600

---

Note: If possible try to avoid using `var` in C#, in this case `string` will do the job.

Comment: In this case I agree with using `string` rather than `var`, but just to clarify: this is merely for readability of the code. Functionally, they are exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

may be u r looking for this..

```
CultureInfo cultureInfoProvider = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

`var lastUpdatedDate = updatedVAlue.Max();` `//value is 20150219A045452.635-5`

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("20150219A045452.635-5", "yyyyMMddtHHmmss.fffz", cultureInfoProvider);
```

Comment: My value is quite different from the one you kept, do check my code once

Comment: Not really flexible,  it will fail for "20150219T045452:6355-5" etc.

Comment: well then in such case.. regular expression should be used to make string compatible with our format and then convert into DateTime

Answer (score 0):

there is problem in 635599184921416348 parts. it is
too lenth, support only max seven digites. try this..

```
CultureInfo cultureInfoProvider = new CultureInfo("en-US");
var lastUpdatedDate = "20150219T045452:6355991";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(lastUpdatedDate, "yyyyMMddTHHmmss:fffffff", cultureInfoProvider);
```