# Datetime conversion using C#

Tags: c#

How to convert  `2016-10-07T15:21` to `dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm` format I have tried with `DateTime.ParseExact` it is giving error

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert DateTime Format c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29070397/convert-datetime-format-c-sharp)

Comment: This question will probably be closed as a duplicate soon. If the answers from the duplicates don't fully address your question please edit it to include why and flag this for re-opening. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try below code :-

```
DateTime dt=DateTime.ParseExact("2016-10-07T15:21", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

**Edited:-**

Sorry just saw "HH:mm", below code will work for you :-

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("2016-10-07T15:21");
string answer = dt.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm");
```

Comment: string answer = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm");

Comment: Please mark it as answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("2016-10-07T15:21");
string convertedDateString = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
```

---

> [Ideone](https://ideone.com/YvrXfw) link for example usage

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTimeOffset.ParseExact("2015-07-09T08:38:49-07:00", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to convert the string ot a real datetime, then you can use `DateTime.ToString` with the proper format string. Note that [`/` is a custom format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#dateSeparator) which will be replaced with the local date separator by default. You can avoid this pitfall by providing `DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo` as second parameter:

```
string input = "2016-10-07T15:21";
DateTime realDateTime = DateTime.Parse(input); // works in this case, if the input can be invalid use DateTime.TryParse or DateTime.TryParseExact
string output = realDateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo); // dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm
```